# Moving Averages for Grouped Data

Tags: grouping, spss, moving-average

I have some data which are grouped by organizational group, and I'd like to compute a moving average, within each group.  I've played around, and don't know a quick and easy way to make the command operate within groups, as opposed to over the entire data set.

Answer (score 0):

See the `SPLIT FILE` command. You can simply specify your grouping variable and run the appropriate `CREATE` command to estimate your moving average. Brief example below:

```
sort cases by GROUPING_VAR.
split file by GROUPING_VAR.
CREATE
  /group_MA=PMA(X 5).
split file off.
```

Comment: Thanks!  I also found useful material at:  http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/faq/create.htm